# jenkins - how to pass a value from bash to groovy?

Tags: bash, groovy, jenkins

I'm working on a jenkins install with two script components. The **bash** bits run first and then **groovy**. I'd like to be able to pass a value (property? Other?) from the bash script->groovy script.

Is this possible? Do I need to write the value to a property file and read it back in groovy?

---

EDIT: my goal from this was to generate a build # in bash and pass this to groovy so I could set the description and build # in the jenkins display. It appears that groovy isn't available on the build server so I'm looking for another direction. Currently experimenting with the 'postbuild' plugin and the 'env-inject' plugin. Open to suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few things to consider to make this successful:

1. Make sure you're trying to accomplish this with one "Execute shell" in Jenkins or from a script.
2. Export the shell variable so that the variable will be present in the child process that will execute your groovy script.

```sh
# foo.sh
export foo=bar
groovy myscript.groovy
```

```sh
# myscript.groovy
def env = System.getenv()
String myvar=env['foo']
println myvar
```

Running foo.sh should produce the following:

```
./foo.sh
bar
```

Comment: I know this is an older post, though my 2 cents: for me, the crucial information here is the point 1: 'Make sure you're trying to accomplish this with _one_ "Execute shell"'. All other answers imply this as well.

Answer (score 2):

If for some reason you prefer *not* to export the variable (there may be good and valid reasons for this), you can still *explicitly* pass the variable to the groovy script as a "system property":

```
# foo.sh
foo=bar
groovy -Dfoo="$foo" yourscript.groovy

# yourscript.groovy
String yourvar = System.properties['foo']
println yourvar
```

which produces the following results:

```
$ ./foo.sh
bar
$
```

Answer (score 2):

I just worked on this problem for days and thought I might share what I discovered.  I had to access a variable in a groovy file from a .sh file and had difficulty at first grabbing the variable.  There is a simple way to do it, though.  Here's what I did:

In your bash file, save the value in a variable.  Then in the groovy script, do this:

```
variableToGet = sh(returnStdout: true, script: """
                . ${DIRECTORY}/bash_file.sh
                echo \$VARIABLE
            """).trim()
```

Hope this helps.  This problem was a good challenge!  It's important to note, however, that standard out will return a String, regardless of what type of variable you are grabbing.  If you need to use an integer value, you can then use the integer value with `Integer.parseInt(variableToGet)`

Answer (score 1):

The best way is setting an environment variable to share the information from bash into groovy.  You could pipe things as well using standard in/out as well.

So if you are setting the env in a bash script it wont be available outside of that script.  Instead of doing a bash script put the script inline in your command in jenkins.  Run your bash code then call the groovy script.

Something like below

```
#do somebash scripting
VARIABLE="something"

#call your groovy code
groovy util.groovy
```

your groovy code (util.groovy):

```
String variable = env['VARIABLE']
```

Comment: I've tried exporting the value (from/in bash) but it doesn't seem available in groovy. How would you recommend setting it? reading it?

Comment: When you say 'put the script inline' - as in 'build' / 'execute shell'? That's what I'm doing now. I'll try adding the groovy file to the project to see if I can call / reference it.